# Django, how to mock annotate?

Tags: python, django, mocking

I want to mock annotate, to see if it was called and the correct parameters where passed.

My query:

```
User.object.filter(pk__in=[1,2,3]).annotate(is_banned=F('profile__is_banned'))
```

Test which is working:

```
@mock.patch('models.User.objects')
def test_method(mock):
    mock.return_value.filter.return_value = QuerySet()
    method_call()
    self.assertEqual(mock.call_count, 1)
    mock.assert_called_with((pk__in=[1,2,3])
```

I can't mock the annotate.

Comment: Have you tried `mock.return_value.filter.return_value.annotate.return_value = MagicMock(return_value=True)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotate is in `mock.filter.return_value.annotate`.